# How to shutdown my ExecutorService object after other activities in other threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

The problem with this is that, since the method "process()" takes quite a while to complete with 10 threads, the tt.shutdownService() got immediately executed. How to ensure the shutdownService() is executed after other threads, i.e. after the process() is executed?

```
public class ThreadTest{

  private ExecturoService service;

  void main(String[] args){
      long startTime = System.currentTimeLillis();

       ThreadTest tt = new ThreadTest();
       tt.process();

       tt.shutdownService();

      long endTime = System.currentTimeLillis();
  }

   public ThreadTest(){
      service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
   }
   public void process(){
        ...
        service.execute(new Runnable){...}
   }

   public void shutdownService(){
       if(service != null){
           service.shutdown();
           service.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
       }
   }
}
```

Note, my actual program is a little more complex. I can't shutdown the service in process(), since process() will be called multiple times in a loop. Here I simplified the case.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown())

*This method does not wait for previously submitted tasks to complete execution. Use awaitTermination to do that.*

Comment: Please see my addition.

Comment: @user697911 Your addition will only wait for 60 seconds, not until all your tasks are done

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `awaitTermination`. This code will actually wait until all the tasks finish. Or until pretty much the end of time, whatever happens first.

```
executor.awaitTermination(Integer.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: In this case, you don't need the service.shutdown() statement?

Comment: You do if you don't want the `Executor` to accept any new tasks. That's what `service.shutdown()` does.

Comment: see the accepted answer in the dupe